# Publish metabox postition?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

On my custom post type when browsing the site on mobile the Publish metabox will land above other metaboxes.
I have changed the position and priority of almost all metaboxes to counter this issue. But there is one metabox I cannot move with priority and context using:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

Is it possible to move the Publish metabox to always be at the bottom when viewing mobile?

It is the default positions I want to change.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the `'submitdiv'` metabox and re-adding it with a low priority this way:

```
function benny_default_position_publish_box() {

    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'post', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'page', 'side' );
    //remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'cpt', 'side' );

    add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', 'post', 'side', 'low' );
    add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', 'page', 'side', 'low' );
    //add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', 'cpt', 'side', 'low' );

}
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'benny_default_position_publish_box' );
```

But if it doesn't work and you only need it for mobile, you could try setting the user options for sorting the metabox like this:

```
function benny_user_option_box_position( $order ) {

  if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {

    return array(
        'normal'   => join( ",", array(
            'postexcerpt',
            'formatdiv',
            'trackbacksdiv',
            'tagsdiv-post_tag',
            'categorydiv',
            'postimagediv',
            'postcustom',
            'commentstatusdiv',
            'slugdiv',
            'authordiv',
            'submitdiv',   // <- keep it last
        ) ),
        'side'     => '',
        'advanced' => '',
    );

  } else {

    return $order;

  }
}
add_filter( 'get_user_option_meta-box-order_post', 'benny_user_option_box_position' );
add_filter( 'get_user_option_meta-box-order_page', 'benny_user_option_box_position' );
//add_filter( 'get_user_option_meta-box-order_cpt', 'benny_user_option_box_position' );
```

I haven't tested it but theoretically it should work

Comment: I have figured out that it doesn't matter which position/priority I have the Publish box set to. `side` metaboxes will always be shown above `advanced` metaboxes (which my custom metabox is). Would it be possible to always show side metaboxes at bottom when using mobile?

Comment: hi @joq3 the second function (`benny_user_option_box_position`) is for you; to test it, try replacing `wp_is_mobile()` with `current_user_can( 'manage_options' )`, if you are the administrator